# Gnuplot, format specifiers: set format y "%1.1t", writes 1.0 instead of 10

Tags: formatting, format, gnuplot, format-specifiers

I am plotting a set of data that is from 5E-5 to 4E-4. 
In order to make the plot according to a editor's request I wrote in the title of the axis (x10^-5) as units.

So, in the Y axis I want to see the tics: ... 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ...
I have played with the specifiers for example

```
set format y "%1.1t"
```

instead I get in the tics   8.0, 9.0, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2

How can I get the values ... 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ... as tics?

Thanks.

Comment: `set format y "%.0t"`?

Comment: You are right. Then you must manually scale your data by the desired factor, like `plot 'file.dat' using 1:($2*1e5)`

Answer (score 0):

The best format ever with gnuplot is :

**`set tics format "%.1s%c"`**

;=> change 10e3 into 10k, 10e6 into 10M, kilo, Mega, Giga, Peta etcétéra

;=> show 10e-3 into 10m, 10e-6 into 10u mili, micro, nano femto etcétéra
For your purpose, you want no suplementary digit after the dots, so your answer is :

**`set tics format "%.0s%c"`**